# When does iTunes Connect update financial reports?

Tags: ios, payment, financial

So, my app was a "hit", and I'm making US$1.2k a day... But I don't see "Payments and Financial Reports" updated for the month of February. If at all I get this payment, this would be my first ever earnings from an iOS app.

On exactly what date (or around what date) does "Payments and Financial Reports" get updated?

@Moderators: You can delete this question if it irrelevant. I posted this here on Stack Overflow only after when I was unable to find it on Google and everywhere... Even if I could find the information, it is outdated. For example, 2009 posts on other forums, etc..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Payments and Financial Reports in Feb will be sent between 13-20 March and you will get paid between 1-8 April.
This is my estimation follow my experience, no guarantee ^^